# HTML5 Like button not showing

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I've HTML5 version of facebook like button on my site since almost an year now but yesterday it stopped showing up.

Check it here: http://www.maximum-tech.net/intel-ivy-bridge-processors-coming-one-week-early-april-23-11577/

The one in the sidebar is the iframe version, its working but there should be a button next to the twitter and G+ button. Its not showing up.

I've posted a bug report on FB too: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/380662258621504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the #fb-root div tag.

Add this to the top of your page, in the  section:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Comment: It is there i think. This line is present:    <div style="float:left; width:75px;" styid="fb-root">  I think it should be styleid, not styid. Right?

Comment: It should just be id, rather than styid, or styled. Ideally, just copy the code I posted, and add that to the top of the page, just after the opening <body> tag.